# Update on view says, 1 row(s) updated, however underlying table is not updated

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

My Oracle database schema is consisting of various tables, and views.
There is a Table A, and View A. View A is simply a Select on Table A with only few columns including primary key.

My user has SELECT and UPDATE permissions on the View, but not on Table.
If I execute a UPDATE statement on the view, it does return a message saying "1 row(s) updated." However, if I fire SELECT statement after the update, it shows old data only. Even table is having old data.

Do I need to have UPDATE rights on the table? If permission is the issue, then should I really be getting that "1 row(s) updated" message?

Comment: Have you committed the update? Oracle would not report that a row was updated if it could not due to insufficient privileges.

Comment: I'm assuming that the "it" in the sentence "it does return a message" refers to SQL*Plus?  Or some other GUI?  Is there an `INSTEAD OF` trigger on the view?

Comment: @David could you please copy your comment into the answer, so I can mark it. Thanks for your suggestion which helped, I am quite a new to Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you committed the update? Oracle would not report that a row was updated if it could not due to insufficient privileges.